# jQuery: Use variables within selector

Tags: jquery

Mind you, I'm not a jQuery guru and just still learning.

I have this looong function:

`$('.client1 > *:first-of-type, .client2 > *:first-of-type, .client3 > *:first-of-type, .client4 > *:first-of-type, .client5 > *:first-of-type').append('<span class="jsi"/>');`

It does work, yes, but I know it's not efficient and not easily scalable because every time I have to add a new 'client' I have to add it to the selector list.

So I know I could use (a) variable(s) for the `> *:first-of-type` part, and maybe an "array" (I don't know if I'm saying that right) for the `.clientX` part.

This is honestly a bit over my head.

This is what I've tried but of course doesn't work:

```
var fot = "> *:first-of-type";
$('.client1' + fot, '.client2' + fot, '.client3' + fot, '.client4' + fot, '.client5' + fot).append('<span class="jsi"/>');
```

What happens is not only I would like to not have to repeat myself but be able to scale this more efficiently as new clients need to be added to the function.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give a common 'client' class instead of 'client1` and 'client2' e.g. `<div class="client client1"></div> <div class="client client2"></div>` then your query is simply: `$('.client > *:first-of-type')`

Comment: Agree Eli, Sven's answer below made me realize that. Gave you an upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an extra class, like `client` and you don't need all that stuff anymore.

```
<div class="client client1">..</div>
<div class="client client2">..</div>
```

So you can select all elements with class `client`.

```
$('.client > *:first-of-type').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span class="jsi" />');
});
```

Comment: Oh boy, I see Sven... I was so FIXED into the `clientX` part that I didn't see your suggestion. Thanks a lot!